# Fail to verify if a pdf is digital signed with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I have a basic test class that use iText for check if a PDF document has a digital signature in it, this is the code:

```
private int getNumFirme(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            java.nio.file.Path pathF = Paths.get(path);
            byte [] bytes =  Files.readAllBytes(pathF);
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
            pathF = null;
            int nFirme = reader.getAcroFields().getSignatureNames().size();
            reader.close();
            return nFirme;
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

This little method has alwyas worked, except for a particular pdf document.
When I use the method for that document the result is 0 (no sign), when I open it with Adobe Acrobat it seems not have any signature (no popup like: "all the signature has verified" or "Almost one signature has problems") and even in the metadata there are no indication of a signature but if I open the file with Dike and I verify it, it contains the digital signature data.

I have read on the Internet that the problem maybe to be that this pdf was signed with a CAdES signature (I'm not an expert of digital signatures and I don't know well the different with the 'normal' PAdES signature) and so the check fails, but I also read that a file signed with a CAdES signature normally has the ".p7m" extension.

It's possible that the documen is signed with a CAdES sign and it has a ".pdf" extesion? Or maybe there is another problem?
In case of the CAdES sign is the problem, how can I verify the signature on the document? (I don't want to know if the signature is valid, I want only to know if the document is signed or not)

Thanks in advice for the help and sorry for my not perfect English

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with CAdES signed or not CAdES signed. If you open it with Adobe Acrobat and it doesn't seem to have a digital signature panel, then it probably doesn't have a digital signature. In which case it's normal that your method returns 0. What makes you think the document is digitally signed? Maybe it just has an image of a signature. That's not the same as a digital signature.

Comment: I have opened the file with Dike and verify it, and Dike says that the file is digital signed, with the data of the signatory, the validity of the signature, the alghoritm digest (SHA-256), the data of sign, the validity of the certification and some other information, I can also save the certificate on a file.

Comment: Show us the file. Maybe it isn't signed at the PDF level.

Comment: Indeed, without seeing the file this amounts to pure guesswork.

Comment: *It's possible that the documen is signed with a CAdES sign and it has a ".pdf" extesion* - do you indeed mean CAdES, not PAdES? Could it be that it is not a PDF with an integrated signature but instead a CMS signature container wrapping the signed data, a PDF? In that case the behavior would be understandable, pdf tools don't find the signature because they look for integrated signatures.

Comment: I can not show the file because it contains medical sensible information. 
However, maybe the file was not sign at the PDF level and so I have to made a test that check the signature in the bytes of the document.
Thank you for the suggestions.